# expected `}' at end of input

Tags: arduino-uno, programming

```
int scvVal = 6;
int drvVal = 9;
int sensorVal = A1;
void setup() { 
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(9, OUTPUT);   
 }
void loop(){
 sensorVal = analogRead(A1);


 Serial.print("Sensor Value: ");
 Serial.print(sensorVal);

 float voltage = (sensorVal*5.0)/1024.0; 
    Serial.print("Volts: ");
    Serial.print(voltage);

 float pressure_pascal = (400.0*((float)voltage-0.5))*1000000.0;
 float pressure_bar = pressure_pascal/10e5;
   Serial.print("Pressure = ");
   Serial.print(pressure_bar); 
   Serial.println(" bars");
   Serial.print("Pressure = ");
   {
 for(int a = 255; a>=0;a--)
 {
   analogWrite(6,a); 
 if (pressure_bar = 1600){
   analogWrite (6, a);
 if (pressure_bar > 1600){
   analogWrite (6, a);
 }
 for(int a = 0; a<256; a++)
 {
  analogWrite(6, a);
 {
 if(pressure_bar < 1600){
  analogWrite (6, a); 
 }
 for(int b = 255; b>=0;b--)
 {
 analogWrite(9, b);
 {
 if (pressure_bar == 1600){
   analogWrite (9, b);
 if(pressure_bar < 1600){
   analogWrite (9, b);
}
 for(int b = 0; b<256; b++)
 {
   analogWrite(9, b);
 { 
if (pressure_bar > 1600){
   analogWrite (9, b);  
   }
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Arduino:SE.  Your life would be so much easier if you indented your code correctly.  It would then be fairly obvious where the missing `}` should be.

Comment: do you help me?

Comment: @Duc Hoang: Are you formatting your code correctly, that it is readable? Select in in the question editor and click on the {} button

Comment: Never before have I see such random use of brackets... ;)

Comment: `do you help me?` .... you have to start by helping yourself ..... read and understand the answers below ..... do not copy and paste code without thinking

Comment: also, what text editor/IDE are you using? Some of them highlight matching brackets abut not Arduino's one

Answer (score 3):

Some guidelines for programming:

**Start each statement on a new line**

```
int scvVal = 6; 
int drvVal = 9; 
int sensorVal = A1; 
void setup() { 
Serial.begin(9600); 
pinMode(6, OUTPUT); 
pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
} void loop(){ 
sensorVal = analogRead(A1);

Serial.print("Sensor Value: "); Serial.print(sensorVal);

float voltage = (sensorVal*5.0)/1024.0; Serial.print("Volts: "); Serial.print(voltage);

float pressure_pascal = (400.0*((float)voltage-0.5))*1000000.0; 
float pressure_bar = pressure_pascal/10e5; 
Serial.print("Pressure = "); 
Serial.print(pressure_bar); 
Serial.println(" bars"); 
Serial.print("Pressure = "); { 
for(int a = 255; a>=0;a--) { 
analogWrite(6,a); 
if (pressure_bar = 1600){ 
analogWrite (6, a); 
if (pressure_bar > 1600){ 
analogWrite (6, a); } 
for(int a = 0; a<256; a++) { 
analogWrite(6, a); { 
if(pressure_bar < 1600){ 
analogWrite (6, a); } 
for(int b = 255; b>=0;b--) { 
analogWrite(9, b); { 
if (pressure_bar == 1600){ 
analogWrite (9, b); 
if(pressure_bar < 1600){ 
analogWrite (9, b); } 
for(int b = 0; b<256; b++) { 
analogWrite(9, b); { 
if (pressure_bar > 1600){ 
analogWrite (9, b);
} }
```

**Use brackets and align them**

.. so each pair of { and } is on the same column and align code with brackets to be indented 2, 3 or 4 spaces

```
int scvVal = 6; 
int drvVal = 9; 
int sensorVal = A1; 
void setup() 
{ 
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
} 
void loop()
{ 
  sensorVal = analogRead(A1);

  Serial.print("Sensor Value: "); 
  Serial.print(sensorVal);

  float voltage = (sensorVal*5.0)/1024.0; Serial.print("Volts: "); 
  Serial.print(voltage);

  float pressure_pascal = (400.0*((float)voltage-0.5))*1000000.0; 
  float pressure_bar = pressure_pascal/10e5; 
  Serial.print("Pressure = "); 
  Serial.print(pressure_bar); 
  Serial.println(" bars"); 
  Serial.print("Pressure = "); 
  { 
    for(int a = 255; a>=0;a--) 
    { 
      analogWrite(6,a); 
      if (pressure_bar = 1600)
      { 
        analogWrite (6, a); 
        if (pressure_bar > 1600)
        { 
          analogWrite (6, a);  
        }   
        for(int a = 0; a<256; a++) 
        { 
          analogWrite(6, a); 
          {   
            if(pressure_bar < 1600)
            {   
              analogWrite (6, a); 
            } 
            for(int b = 255; b>=0;b--) 
            { 
              analogWrite(9, b); 
              {  
                if (pressure_bar == 1600)
                { 
                  analogWrite (9, b); 
                  if(pressure_bar < 1600)
                  {  
                    analogWrite (9, b); 
                  } 
                  for(int b = 0; b<256; b++) 
                  { 
                    analogWrite(9, b); 
                    { 
                      if (pressure_bar > 1600)
                      {    
                        analogWrite (9, b);
                      }
                    }
```

**Remove superfluous brackets**

As you can see, you are having some superfluous/missing brackets. What you want is probably something like:

```
int scvVal = 6; 
int drvVal = 9; 
int sensorVal = A1; 
void setup() 
{ 
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
} 
void loop()
{ 
  sensorVal = analogRead(A1);

  Serial.print("Sensor Value: "); 
  Serial.print(sensorVal);

  float voltage = (sensorVal*5.0)/1024.0; Serial.print("Volts: "); 
  Serial.print(voltage);

  float pressure_pascal = (400.0*((float)voltage-0.5))*1000000.0; 
  float pressure_bar = pressure_pascal/10e5; 
  Serial.print("Pressure = "); 
  Serial.print(pressure_bar); 
  Serial.println(" bars"); 
  Serial.print("Pressure = "); 

  for(int a = 255; a>=0;a--) 
  { 
    analogWrite(6,a); 
    if (pressure_bar = 1600)
    { 
      analogWrite (6, a);
    }
    if (pressure_bar > 1600)
    { 
      analogWrite (6, a);  
    } 
  }
  for(int a = 0; a<256; a++) 
  {
    analogWrite(6, a); 
    if(pressure_bar < 1600)
    {   
      analogWrite (6, a); 
    }
  } 
  for(int b = 255; b>=0;b--) 
  { 
    analogWrite(9, b); 
    if (pressure_bar == 1600)
    { 
      analogWrite (9, b); 
    }
    if(pressure_bar < 1600)
    {  
      analogWrite (9, b); 
    } 
  }
  for(int b = 0; b<256; b++) 
  { 
    analogWrite(9, b); 
    if (pressure_bar > 1600)
    {    
      analogWrite (9, b);
    }
  }
}
```

**Remove duplicate code**

In the if statement, you perform twice the same code (both you send an `analogWrite` with the same value, so the code (from the for loops can be reduced to:

```
  for(int a = 255; a>=0;a--) 
  { 
    analogWrite(6,a); 
    if (pressure_bar >= 1600)
    { 
      analogWrite (6, a);
    }
  }
  for(int a = 0; a<256; a++) 
  {
    analogWrite(6, a); 
    if(pressure_bar <= 1600)
    {   
      analogWrite (6, a); 
    }
  } 
  for(int b = 255; b>=0;b--) 
  { 
    analogWrite(9, b); 
    if (pressure_bar <= 1600)
    { 
      analogWrite (9, b); 
    } 
  }
  for(int b = 0; b<256; b++) 
  { 
    analogWrite(9, b); 
    if (pressure_bar >= 1600)
    {    
      analogWrite (9, b);
    }
  }
}
```

**Unclear**

What is unclear why you first write an analog value, and directly afterward (in each if) you write the same value. I'm not sure what you really want here. Either you want to write to a different pin, or you want a delay (to have the value having some effect), I'm just not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your open brackets { vs closing brackets, }. You need the same number of each. If have this in the Arduino IDE and use CTRL-T, they are somewhat easy to find.  I just looked, and I can spot them pretty easily.

```
int scvVal = 6; 
int drvVal = 9; 
int sensorVal = A1; 
void setup() 
{ 
Serial.begin(9600); 
pinMode(6, OUTPUT); 
pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
} 
void loop()
{ 
sensorVal = analogRead(A1);
Serial.print("Sensor Value: "); 
Serial.print(sensorVal);
float voltage = (sensorVal*5.0)/1024.0; 
Serial.print("Volts: "); 
Serial.print(voltage);
float pressure_pascal = (400.0*((float)voltage-0.5))*1000000.0; 
float pressure_bar = pressure_pascal/10e5; 
Serial.print("Pressure = "); 
Serial.print(pressure_bar); 
Serial.println(" bars"); 
Serial.print("Pressure = "); 
{                            << bracket for what?
for(int a = 255; a>=0;a--) { << missing closing bracket
  analogWrite(6,a); 
  if (pressure_bar = 1600){   << missing closing bracket
   analogWrite (6, a); 
     if (pressure_bar > 1600){ 
     analogWrite (6, a); 
     } 
  for(int a = 0; a<256; a++) { 
    analogWrite(6, a); 
    {                      << wrong direction
    if(pressure_bar < 1600){ 
       analogWrite (6, a); 
    } 
  for(int b = 255; b>=0;b--) { 
    analogWrite(9, b); 
   {                           << wrong direction
    if (pressure_bar == 1600){ << missing closing bracket
      analogWrite (9, b); 
      if(pressure_bar < 1600){ << missing closing bracket
        analogWrite (9, b); 
    } 
   for(int b = 0; b<256; b++) { 
     analogWrite(9, b); 
   {                            << wrong direction
   if (pressure_bar > 1600){ 
     analogWrite (9, b);
   } 
}  << closing bracket for loop
```